# Trying to Create an Enterprise Provisioning Profile--Distribution Tab is Missing

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm attempting to create an Enterprise Provisioning Profile, but the program portal isn't working the way I expect it to (based on the documentation).  Here's what I'm seeing:

First, I log on as the Team Agent.

Second, I navigate to the Provisioning section of the program portal.

According to the documentation, I should see 4 tabs at this point:  Development, Distribution, History, How To.  But when I do this, the Distribution tab isn't there.  And without the Distribution tab, I can't create a Enterprise Provisioning Profile (or an Ad Hoc one, for that matter).

I've tried contacting Apple administrative support, but they weren't able to provide any help with this.  They suggested that I try the forum.  :-)

Just to fill in a few more details:  My company has an enterprise membership in the developer program.  And when I navigate to the Certificates section, there is a Distribution tab.

I figure that there must be something that I've done incorrectly.  Has anyone had a similar experience?  Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Turns out that it was an error on Apple's web portal.  After several months of reporting the problem and working through a variety of channels, they finally fixed the portal and I'm now able to create an Enterprise Provisioning Profile.

Comment: I discovered it is important to ensure enrollment in the right program to create an Enterprise Distribution profile thanks to your "more details". Its so obvious now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, and I guess it's the same with you, is that I was an Admin of the account, not the Agent. Only Agents can create Distribution Certificates and Provisioning files.
Hope that works for you as well.